# Sending UDP packet but not sure if devices are answering

Tags: python, python-sockets

I am attempting to broadcast a specific number on a specific port where a certain set of devices will respond once they see that number. The devices will respond with the following info:

> MAC = 00:12:34:56:78:9a
>   IP = 10.17.253.98
>   Network Acquisition Mode = DHCP
>   Supported Protocol Version = 3
>   Vendor = Legacy
>   Product = USB
>   Firmware = 1.8.5

Here is what I have started. The specific number is "222456", the port is 12345, and the subnet to broadcast is 10.17.253

```
import socket

from socket import *
cs = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
cs.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
cs.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, 1)
cs.sendto('222456', ('10.17.253.255', 12345))

from socket import *
s=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
s.bind(('',12345))
while(1):
    m=s.recvfrom(8192)
    print 'len(m)='+str(len(m))
    print 'len(m[0])='+str(len(m[0]))    
    print m[0]

    print 'len(m[1])='+str(len(m[1]))    
    print m[1]
```

Looking at wireshark, I see "222456" being broadcasted over port 12345. However, the return that I am getting is this:

```
len(m)=2
len(m[0])=10
/ô¢
len(m[1])=2
('10.17.253.22', 6971)
```

Along with not getting what I should be getting, the IP that is returned is not the correct IP. I also have no idea what `/ô¢` means.

Comment: It appears that the device is returning binary data - try `print repr(m[0])` to perhaps get a better idea of the bytes that are actually there.  Where did that example info display come from?  If it's from some existing piece of software, it's probably doing the conversion to human-readable form itself.

Comment: Thanks. That was it. That example came from the manufacturers manual on what to expect as a return.

Answer (score 0):

when you are trying send a message with socket, you need make a object serialization with pickle, json or a simple decode. If you want send a str I think the best way is make a .decode, but if you need send more than a str, you can put the information on a list and use pickle or json to make the object serialization, and maybe you can change this and put the object serialization on sendto.

```
m=s.recvfrom(8192)
```

to this

```
data, addr =s.recvfrom(1024)
```

I don't remember why, but put 1024 is the most efficienty method (I think), and after get the data make the reverse of object serialization, .encode if you use .decode and for pickle .loads. If you are using Python 2 I think you can use cPickle to do this. In Python 3 cPickle don't exist, but his methods is on pickle lib.